# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(passation.datepassation, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')"

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to add date but i had this error when i save my form Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(passation.datepassation, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')"

1-Thymeleaf:

```
`<label>Date:</label>
 <label 
 th:object="${passation}" 
 th:value="${#dates.format(passation.datepassation, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}" ></label>
```

2- class Passation

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date datepassation;
```

3-in controller:

```
   @Autowired(required=true)
   private PassationRepository passationRepository;
  @RequestMapping(value="/passation",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String passation(Model model){

    List<Passation> passations=passationRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listPassations",passations);

    model.addAttribute("Date",new Date());    //add new date
    return "passation";
}
```

`
any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your form is expecting an object called `passation` to be added to the model, so you'll want to have this in your controller.  You should also post the full stack trace/error message while posting to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `passation` is null.  So however you're creating the bean, make sure that `passation` is not null and `datepassation` is set on the bean.

```
@Autowired
private PassationRepository passationRepository;

@GetMapping("/passation") //note shorthand
public String passation(Model model) {

   List<Passation> passations = passationRepository.findAll();
   model.addAttribute("listPassations", passations);

   // This should be in your service layer.  Example only:
   Passation passation = new Passation();
   passation.setDatepassation(new Date());

   //make sure the model has the bean
   model.addAttribute("passation", passation); 
   return "passation";
}
```

This HTML will print the value from the bean.

```
<label>Date:</label>
<span th:text="${#dates.format(passation.datepassation, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}">No date found</span>
```

If you're looking to update the bean values, use `th:object` within a `<form>` tag.

Comment: another question @bphilipnyc please,I have two other date (return-validation) how I handle each date according to an action and it does not take a system date(remains unchangeable)?

Comment: Hmm - can you please search SO for an answer and post another question if you don't find an answer?  You'd be best off providing a code example if you really can't find an answer.